# Numpy: Select where index is the same

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a multidimensional matrix

```
A = np.ones((5, 10, 5, 10, 2, 3))
```

and now I want to select all items where the *index* of the first dimension is equal to the third dimension. That is, I want to have

```
A[0, :, 0, ...]
A[1, :, 1, ...]
A[2, :, 2, ...]
```

and so on....

A  complicated (but known to me) way to do that is to create a meshgrid over the indices and then select based on those:

```
i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6 = np.meshgrid(range(5), range(10), range(5), range(10), range(2), range(3), indexing='ij')

A[i1 == i3].shape
Out[29]: (3000,)
A[i1 == i2].shape
Out[31]: (1500,)
```

However, this is a quite tedious way of doing this. Is there any simpler way of selecting based on the index?

**Bonus question**

How would I select on two indices at the same time? ie

```
A[(i1 == i3) and (i2 == i4)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty simple with [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) (simple and advanced together, hmm...) -

```
r = np.arange(a.shape[0])
out = a[r,:,r]
```

**Sample runs**

1) `3D` data :

```
In [380]: a
Out[380]: 
array([[[4, 6, 4, 8],
        [0, 4, 5, 2],
        [2, 5, 6, 7]],

       [[0, 0, 4, 6],
        [1, 7, 4, 3],
        [4, 2, 0, 1]]])

In [381]: a[0,:,0]
Out[381]: array([4, 0, 2])

In [382]: a[1,:,1]
Out[382]: array([0, 7, 2])

In [383]: r = np.arange(a.shape[0])

In [384]: a[r,:,r]
Out[384]: 
array([[4, 0, 2],
       [0, 7, 2]])
```

2) 4D data :

```
In [385]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,2,3,4))

In [386]: a[0,:,0,:]
Out[386]: 
array([[0, 4, 1, 8],
       [1, 2, 2, 3]])

In [387]: a[1,:,1,:]
Out[387]: 
array([[7, 8, 3, 8],
       [0, 1, 4, 7]])

In [388]: r = np.arange(a.shape[0])

In [389]: a[r,:,r]
Out[389]: 
array([[[0, 4, 1, 8],
        [1, 2, 2, 3]],

       [[7, 8, 3, 8],
        [0, 1, 4, 7]]])
```

---

**Bonus part : Selecting from two pairs of dimensions**

Simply (again) use two range arrays for indexing, but *orthogonal to each other* by getting the first one on the other axis to allow for pairings and then index, like so -

```
r1 = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
r2 = np.arange(a.shape[1])
out = a[r1,r2,r1,r2]
```

Sample run -

```
In [464]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(3,2,3,2))

In [470]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     for j in range(2):
     ...:         print a[i,j,i,j]
     ...:         
34
12
30
20
93
76

In [471]: r1 = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
     ...: r2 = np.arange(a.shape[1])
     ...: out = a[r1,r2,r1,r2]
     ...: 

In [472]: out
Out[472]: 
array([[34, 12],
       [30, 20],
       [93, 76]])
```

Comment: Looks good so far. I'm ultimately trying to select on two dimensions at the same time - didn't expose that for the sake of simplicity, but `a[r1, r2, r1, r2, ...]` at least appears not to work - you have a guess on that one too? (see edited question)